# Card problem - combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Deal a pokerhand (5 cards) with 5 different ranks and 4 different suits.

EG:

```
2♠ (spades)
3♥ (hearts)
4♦ (diamonds)
5♣ (clubs)
6♠ (spades)
```

I have been told that this is the solution:
$\binom{13}{5}\binom{4}{1}\binom{5}{2}\times 3\times 2$

I'm trying to solve it like this, and I really cannot see why it wouldn't work (it is wrong):

$\binom{13}{1}\times 4\binom{12}{1}\times 3\binom{11}{1}\times 2\binom{10}{1}\binom{9}{1}\times 4$

Explaining how I was thinking:

1. Choose 1 card out of 13 - 4 possible colors. $\binom{13}{1}\times 4$.
2. Choose 1 card out of 12 - 3 possible colors. $\binom{12}{1}\times 3$.
3. Choose 1 card out of 11 - 2 possible colors. $\binom{11}{1}\times 3$.
4. Choose 1 card out of 10 - 1 possible color. $\binom{10}{1}\times 1$.
5. Now I have 4 cards, 4 different suits and 4 different ranks.
6. Choose 1 card out of 9 - 4 possible colors. $\binom{9}{1}\times 4$.

Then just multiply everything together, why doesn't this work..?

Comment: With poker hands, we usually don't care about the order in which cards appear.  Choosing these results in the following order yield the same outcome: $(A\spadesuit),(2\heartsuit) ,(3\clubsuit),(4\diamondsuit),(5\spadesuit)$ and $(2,\heartsuit),(A\spadesuit), (3\clubsuit),(4\diamondsuit), (5\spadesuit)$.  You counted the number of ways in which five cards may be drawn in a specific order where all cards are different ranks and the first four suits are different.  As a result, you have overcounted.

Comment: with that sort of logic you tend to have to branch off for the draws after (2) depending on whether or not they have drawn the second of a colour

Answer (score 1):

- Your answer cares about the order you receive cards in; you count as different the two sets

  > 2♠ 3♥ 4♦ 5♣ 6♠

  and

  > 3♥ 2♠ 4♦ 5♣ 6♠

  so you are not correctly enumerating only different **combinations**. You count some things too many times.
- If you had correctly counted all **permutations**, you would just be able to divide by $5!$ at the end and still get the right answer - however, you haven't quite counted all permutations either, because you have insisted that you get the duplicate suit as the last card. In fact, for every possible **combination**, your approach lists it exactly 48 times.

  Why? Look at the example. You could choose either the 2♠ or 6♠ for your special last card (a factor of $2$). You could also then have the first four cards in any order, giving $4! = 24$ further choices.

So it is possible to obtain the answer from your result by dividing by 48.

---

**Edit**: Of course, this isn't the easiest way to get the answer. Their form of the answer is reasoned as follows:

- Each combination has exactly $5$ of the $13$ ranks, hence a $13 \choose 5$ factor.
- Exactly $1$ of the $4$ suits appears twice, hence $4 \choose 1$.
- Exactly $2$ of the $5$ cards are this special suit, hence $5 \choose 2$.
- The remaining $3$ suits and $3$ cards can be matched up in exactly $3! = 3\times 2 \times 1$ ways, hence the last term.

Answer (score 0):

You over count. Your method considers selecting $2\heartsuit,3\spadesuit,4\clubsuit,5\diamondsuit,$ then $6\spadesuit$ for the extra as distinct from $2\heartsuit,6\spadesuit,4\clubsuit,5\diamondsuit,$ then $3\spadesuit$ as the extra.

---

To have five different ranks and four different suits you must have two cards of one suit and one each of the other three.

- select 5 from 13 ranks.
- select 1 from 4 suits as the doubled suit.
- arrange 4 singletons and 1 double; matching suits to ranks by:

  - selecting the two cards to have the doubled suit
  - arranging the single suits among the remaining three

> $${^{13}\mathrm C_4}{^{4}\mathrm C_1}{^{5}\mathrm C_{2}}3!$$